# How to address 'saveGraphic: Method not found' error in automating the generation of figures in avogadro using Python?

Tags: python, visualization-software, avogadro

My question is a follow-up question to this [question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11421/5) posted by Hemanth Haridas.

I ran the example .py script in Geoff Hutchison's answer for the above mentioned question to generate .png files from .xyz files in avogadro using python.

The script is available here : [Script-Github](https://gist.github.com/ghutchis/940b3f094969c515d02074bd9cb92c2b)

I ran the script on my local Mac OS. The python script is in the same directory as the .xyz files. This is the output for one file:

```
Opening mol2.xyz
b'{\n    "id": 0,
\n  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
\n "result": true\n}
\n'
b'{\n "error": 
{\n  "code": -32601,\n  
"data":
 {\n  "request": 
{\n   "id": 0,
\n   "jsonrpc": "2.0",\n                

"method": "saveGraphic",
\n "params": 
{\n                    

"fileName":
"/Users/aimun/
avogadroextract/mol2.png"\n   }
\n   }\n   },\n        

"message":
 "Method not found"\n    },\n   
 "id": 0,\n "jsonrpc": "2.0"\n}\n'
```

The same error is displayed for all the other .xyz files in the directory.

I have Avogadro 1.97.0 and Avogadro 1.2.0 installed in my mac. When I run the script, I see only the Avogadro 1.97.0 window being updated with the molecule structures, however, the files are not saved as .png.

According to [json-rpc 2.0 specification](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification), `code: -32601` means 'The method does not exist / is not available'.

Any leads on how to address this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add which version of Avagadro you are using in the question

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the post with the Avogadro version details.

Comment: The answer by Geoff that you linked in the question, mentions that the Avagadro version 1.98. So please upgrade your version to 1.98 and retry since the method could have been added in 1.98.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my [answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/11461/30), this is only available in the development version, which will be released as 1.98 soon. So if you're running 1.97 release, the method is not available.

In principal, you can use a nightly build from https://two.avogadro.cc

I would suggest posting questions to the [Avogadro forum](https://discuss.avogadro.cc/) since I don't come here often.

Comment: In addition to asking users to post Avogadro questions to the Avogadro forum, I wonder if you knew that you can [get emails whenever someone asks a StackExchange question with the Avogadro tag](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/60/5)? That might be an easier way to cover both grounds in case some people are reluctant to create user IDs and passwords on other forums. Incidentally, I just tried to sign up for the Avogadro forum but [can't see a login button, probably because I'm using an old version of Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3pDa.png) (my computer's from 2016, hahaha).